# How can I remove the Documents and Pictures folders from the Indexing options?

Tags: windows, windows-10, search-indexing

Is there a way to remove both `Documents` and `Pictures` folder from the Indexing options ?

When I select any folder but those two in the bottom part of the window, it automatically jumps to the folder in the top part where I can unselect it. But when I select `Documents` or `Pictures`, nothing happens thus I don't know how to remove them from the list.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders corresponded to folders in my OneDrive:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Seems easily to uncheck the Documents and Pictures under your user name and Public user name:
[image]